# Python - Running code over (iterating?) only works once

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, python-3.5

please excuse any errors as this is my first post.

I'm a Computing student and I've missed out on several weeks of teaching so I'm not properly prepared for my task. I'm making a population model which needs to be able to do a number of calculations a variable number of times, then add the result of each calculation to a corresponding list.

I'm really having trouble with getting the code to run over and over again (is this called iterating?) while each time adding to the list.

As far as I can tell, this is the problematic bit of code and I'm at my wit's end trying to make it work!

```
for x in (0, numberGens):
                    juvNew = aduOverGens[-1]*birthRate
                    juvOverGens +=("Gen ", x+1, ": ", juvNew)
                    print (juvOverGens)
```

Where numberGens is the is the number of times the code should repeat over, and aduOverGens is a predefined list containing the data for the first generation of a certain type of individual, and juvNew is the result of the calculations, that should be added to the end of the list each time. When I run the code with numberGens as 10 aduOverGens[-1] as 22 and birthRate as 2, I would expect to see the following result: 10 prints of the list juvOverGens with one extra value added at the end each time, which should be double the last value of aduOverGens (which in this case will be the same each time because no extra values are added to aduOverGens as yet).

However in practise, the printed result is:

```
['Gen 0: ', 22.0, 'Gen ', 1, ': ', 44.0]
['Gen 0: ', 22.0, 'Gen ', 1, ': ', 44.0, 'Gen ', 11, ': ', 44.0]
```

So that's actually just printed the starting generation (as I expected) then added the value of the first generation (44, as expected) but then skipped out the rest to end up only printing the last generation (which due to a different error on my part is labelled Gen 11), instead of printing the list the right number of times with an extra value added to the end.

How can I make this work so that it prints the right number of generations in the list, rather than missing out 2-10 in there? Also as a side question can I stop the list from printing out with the '' and commas and gaps between 'Gen ', 1, ': ', [value] ?

Sorry for such a long prose but I can't help it sometimes... Thanks in advance!

Comment: run this code to understand some of what is happening: for x in (0, numberGens): print x

Comment: `for x in (0, numberGens):` will iterate twice. You're probably looking for `for x in range(0, numberGens)` instead.

Comment: You couldn't let Crackers figure that out? :)

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the solution in the end ;) As I said, I'm a beginner to all this. I can't believe I didn't spot that I needed 'range' in there...

Comment: @KennyOstrom You're right, I should have realized that you were trying to teach by suggesting debugging rather than giving away the solution. It just seems futile; someone always answers immediately anyway (and someone did). In fact, given the silly reputation point system, I can only conclude that teaching/nudging is indirectly discouraged on SO. Maybe, one day we'll get a "class in session"-button that you can click to let the rest of us know that we shouldn't answer right away. Anyway, I'll shut up next time I see you suggesting adding print statements somewhere :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(0, NumberGens)` is literally a tuple with two numbers: 0 and whatever NumberGens is. Presumably you actually wanted to iterate over a range from one to the other, in which case you need to use the `range` function.

```
for x in range(0, numberGens):
```

Note that normally in Python you'd iterate directly over your object; you haven't shown all the code but you might be able to do:

```
for gen in addOverGens:
    juvNew = gen * birthRate
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Wow, I feel seriously stupid for not getting that by myself. As I said - I'm a beginner! With the addition of 'range' I now get the expected result. Cheers!